# Prefetch or annotate Django model with the foreign key of a related object

Tags: django, prefetch

Let's say we have the following models:

```
class Author(Model):
    ...
class Serie(Model):
    ...
class Book(Model):
    authors = ManyToManyField(Author, related_name="books")
    serie = ForeignKey(Serie)
    ...
```

How can I get the list of authors, with their series ?

I tried different combinations of `annotate` and `prefetch`:

---

```
list_authors = Author.objects.prefetch(Prefetch("books__series", queryset=Serie.objects.all(), to_attr="series"))
```

Trying to use `list_authors[0].series` throws an exception because `Author` has no `series` field

---

```
list_authors = Author.objects.annotate(series=FilteredExpression("books__series", condition=Q(...))
```

Trying to use `list_authors[0].series` throws an exception because `Author` has no `series` field

---

```
list_authors = Author.objects.annotate(series=F('books__series'))
```

returns all possible combinations of (author, serie) that have a book in common

---

As I'm using PostgreSQL for my database, I tried:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
...
list_authors = Author.objects.annotate(series=ArrayAgg('books__serie', distinct=True, filter=Q(...)))
```

It works fine, but returns only the `id` of the related objects.

```
list_authors = Author.objects.annotate(series=ArrayAgg(
    Subquery(
        Serie.objects.filter(
            livres__auteurs=OuterRef('pk'),
            ...
        ).prefetch_related(...)
    )
 ))
```

fails because it needs an `output_field`, and a `Model` is not a valid value for `output_field`

*BUT*
I can get the number of series for an author, so why not the actual list of them:

```
list_authors = Author.objects.annotate(nb_series=Count("books__series", filter=Q(...), distinct=True)
list_authors[0].nb_series
>>> 2
```

Thus I assume that what I try to do is possible, but I am at a loss regarding the "How"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with an annotation on the `Author` queryset - as you've already found you can do `F('books__series')` but that will not return distinct results. Annotations generally only make sense if the result is a single value per row.

What you could do instead is have a method on the `Author` model that fetches all the series for that author with a relatively simple query. This will mean one additional query per author, but I can't see any alternative. Something like this:

```
class Author:

    def get_series(self):
        return Serie.objects.filter(book__authors=self).distinct()
```

Then you just do:

```
list_authors = Author.objects.all()
list_authors[0].get_series()
```

Comment: Actually, with the `distinct` parameter, the `Count` counts only distinct items ;)

Comment: Yeah, okay. You still can't fetch the actual list of items in an annotation though.